# Add null-like value to String in Java

Tags: java, string, object

I am writing test method like `setTask(Task task)`. And `Task` object has several fields, e.g.

```
public String vehicle;
```

Method `setTask` should be used in different test-cases, so I'd like to have an options for this field to accept values:

- `null` - the method should not do anything in this particulare case;
- `some string value` - e.g. `"", "Hello, World!", "Iso Isetta", ...`
- `random` - a value that indicates (as well as null indicates "no changes") that a random value should be selected for a drop-down list corresponding to this field.

So what can I do to make `String` to be `SpecialString` which could accept values `null`, `random` & `some string value`? (BTW: I don't want to set it to string value "RANDOM", and chech whether the value is equal to "RANDOM"-string)

**UPDATE:** I don't mean `random` like `random value from a set of values`, I mean `random` as well as `null` and this is for `setTask()` to handle `random` (select random from drop-down), and not to pass a random string from a set of values.

Pseudocode:

```
Task task = new Task();
task.vehicle = random;   // as well as null

setTask(task)
```

in setTask(Task task):

```
if (task.vehicle == null) {
    //skip
} else if (task.vehicle == random) {
    // get possible values from drop-down list
    // select one of them
} else {
    // select value from drop-down list which is equal to task.vehicle
}
```

Comment: It sounds like I misunderstood your question. Could you post a pseudocode sampe of how you think it should look like?

Comment: @daniu , added. As you can see set of values is only know at the set stage. Ok, it is possible to get this set of values before passing it to `setTask` but it will break code structure

Comment: In second else, you are expecting comparison with list values??

Comment: @Simmant , no, there is nothing to compare with (I can assign these actions to `null` value of `task.vehicle` and move them to first `if`. So should I compare anything with `null` - no). Just selecting any random value from a set.

Answer (score 6):

Don't assign a fixed `String` but use a `Supplier<String>` which can generate a `String` dynamically:

```
public Supplier<String> vehicleSupplier;
```

This, you can assign a generator function as you request:

```
static Supplier<String> nullSupplier () { return () -> null; }
static Supplier<String> fixedValueSupplier (String value) { return () -> value; }
static Supplier<String> randomSupplier (String... values) {
    int index = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(values.length) -1;
    return index > 0 && index < values.length ? values[index] : null;
}
```

In use, this looks like:

```
task.setVehicleSupplier(nullSupplier()); // or
task.setVehicleSupplier(fixedValueSupplier("value")); // or
task.setVehicleSupplier(randomSupplier("", "Hello, World!", "Iso Isetta"));
```

and you can get the String by

```
String value = task.vehicleSupplier().get();
```

or hide the implementation in a getter function

```
class Task {
    // ...
    private Supplier<String> vehicleSupplier;
    public void setVehicleSupplier(Supplier<String> s) { 
        vehicleSupplier = s; 
    }
    public String getVehicle() {
        return vehicleSupplier != null ? vehicleSupplier.get() : null;
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! To clear up things: I don't mean `random` like `random value from a set of values`, I mean `random` as well as `null` and this is for `setTask()` to handle `random` (select random from drop-down), and not just to  pass random string from a set of values.

Answer (score 1):

What you may want to do is to create an object that wraps a string as well as some information about whether or not it's a special value. Something along the lines of...

```
public class Special<T> {
    public enum Type {
        NOTHING, RANDOM, SPECIFIC
    }

    private final Type type;
    private final T specificValue;

    public Special(Type type, T specificValue) {
        this.type = type;
        this.specificValue = specificValue;
    }

    public Type getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public T getSpecificValue() {
        if (type != SPECIFIC) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Value is not specific");
        }
        return specificValue;
    }
}
```

The class above could be used like so:

```
Special<String> a = new Special<>(Special.Type.NOTHING, null);
Special<String> b = new Special<>(Special.Type.SPECIFIC, "Hello");

if (b.getType() == Special.Type.RANDOM) {
    // do something
}else if (b.getType() == Special.Type.SPECIFIC) {
    String val = b.getSpecificValue();
    // do something else
}
```

A slightly more polished variant of the thing above is probably the best way, but there is a way, a much uglier way, to do it using nothing but a `String` field.

What you could do is to have a "magical" string instance that behaves differently from all other string instances, despite having the same value. This would be done by having something like

`static final String SPECIAL_VALUE_RANDOM = new String("random");`

Note the use of the `String` constructor, which ensures that the string becomes a unique, non-interned instance. You can then say `if (vehicle == SPECIAL_VALUE_RANDOM) { ... }` (note the use of `==` instead of `.equals()`) to check if that specific instance (rather than any other string that says "random") was used.

Again, this is not a particularly good way of doing this, especially if you intend to do this more than once ever. I would strongly suggest something closer to the first way.

Comment: Could you write a simple `StringWrapper` so I could accept this answer? Also like idea of unique string instance

Comment: @IvanGerasimenko I added a draft of what such a class may look like. There's a lot of ways it can be done; that one's just off the top of my head.

Comment: Please, check my edit: I'd like to simplify constructor but have some doubts

Comment: Edit was rejected so I'll post it in comments:
    public Special() {
        this.type = Type.NOTHING;
        this.specificValue = null;
    }

    public Special(Type type) {
        // some hesitations about this constructor
        // in case of Type.SPECIFIC and specificValue = null
        // also throw new IllegalStateException("Type could not be specific"); is not good idea
        // because it's runtime error but (logically) this restriction should be applied on compilation time
        this.type = type;
        this.specificValue = null;
    }

Comment: public Special(T value) {
        if (value == null) {
            this.type = Type.NOTHING;
            this.specificValue = null;
        } else {
            this.type = SPECIFIC;
            this.specificValue = value;
        }
    }

Comment: @GBlodgett , does code look nice in comment??? Edit was much better idea